# Applymap on all but one Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df` that looks like this:

```
    0       1   2   3   4   5
0   first   M   A   F   I   L
1   second  M   A   F   I   L
2   third   M   S   F   I   I
3   fourth  M   S   F   I   L
4   fifth   M   L   F   F   I
```

I would like to change each element of each column *except for the first* to its corresponding integer ASCII code (i.e. "M" gets mapped to the integer 77, "A" gets mapped to 65, etc.).

I can achieve this result with the following:

```py
new_df = df.loc[:, 1:].applymap(ord)
new_df.insert(0, 0, df[0])
```

Is there a better way to do this? There must be a better way to do this than by creating a new DataFrame. Perhaps a way to do `applymap` in-place on a subset of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign to selected columns:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].applymap(ord)
```

Or:

```
df.loc[:, 1:] = df.loc[:, 1:].applymap(ord)
```